# Is it possible to build a rocket with 2kg payload?

Tags: rockets, payload

Is it possible to build a small rocket that carries 1 cubesat into orbit?
And how small the rocket would be, if it is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate? (with six answers!) [Why isn't there a rocket to launch a single cubesat?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36261/12102) Also see [How small could an orbital rocket be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18789/12102) and [Do launchers using only solid propellant exist?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26693/12102) and my favorite [If there “won't be” rockets to launch individual cubesats, then why did JAXA build exactly that? (SS-520-xx)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37909/12102)

Comment: and don't forget [Will JAXA try again to launch TRICOM-1 with the “world's smallest orbital rocket” SS-520-4 again?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22471/12102) with some nice photos

Comment: Possible? Yes. Economical? ...

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be possible?

Answer (score 25):

The [SS-520-5 rocket from Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Series_(rocket_family)) is probably as close you can get with 4kg to orbit.

Height: 9.54 meters
Weight: 2600 kg
Diameter: 52 cm

Comment: ... price? (ok, if you have to ask, you can't afford it)

Comment: @Brian Drummond there does not apear to be an official price as this is an experimental launch and not a comercial rocket system